# Run code after function inside function javascript

Tags: javascript, function, return

I have this function:

```
function start_all(id) {

document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Starting...";

start(id); // This print too a status on the "status" div like: ID started

document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Done...";

}
```

My problem is that the last line is running before the function start(id); and I need to run on the order.

My result is:

```
Starting...
Done...
ID started
```

And I need like this:

```
Starting...
ID started
Done...
```

Comment: That you need to use promises or callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function start_all(id) {

document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Starting...";

start(id,function(){
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Done...";

});

}
```

This is called callback

Comment: THe function start() is fixed I cant change it because is used on another area.

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```js
   document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Starting...";
var status_id = start(id) // a string that returns the text 'ID Started'
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = status_id;
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Done...";
```

Comment: THe function start() is fixed I cant change it because is used on another area.